# Factory_girl using #create_list, share the same associations between all created objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Consider the following associations:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :foobar
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end

class Foobar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end
```

And here are my factories so far:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blog do
    user
    foobar
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foobar do
  end
end
```

Here is what I want to do:  I want to use `create_list` to create 5 `blogs`.  However: I want all the `blogs` to be associated to the same `user` record and the same `foobar` record.  In other words: I want all 5 `blogs` to have the *exact same* `user_id` and `foobar_id`.

I did look through the [factory_girl docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).  This specific scenario is tripping me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to assign the relationships like other attributes. e.g:

```
user = create(:user)
foobar = create(:foobar)
blogs = create_list(:blog, 5, user: user, foobar: foobar)
```